# What's the meaning of this sentence:

Tags: sentence-meaning

What's the meaning of this sentence:
"I knew, **in a way that I could think better than I could say**, that it was different."

I suppose that its meaning is that "he understands the difference but cannot describe it well."

Is that right?!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have interpreted the sentence correctly.

The original sentence could also be shortened to

> I knew, **in a way better than I could say/describe**, that it was different.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure the shortened version works. Maybe if it were further shortened by omitting "in a way." But I don't think the original needs shortening. Its use of "think" is just a little odd, but its simplicity is attractive. Maybe it's in the voice of a young person or someone who wouldn't use a more complicated word like "intuit" or "conceptualize."